# spresense sdk での millis関数の実装について

Tags: spresense

現在 arduino IDEで作成したプログラムを、もう少し細かく制御したくspresense SDKに
移植する作業をしています。
その中で、`millis()`関数がspresense SDKには存在しない様でした。
代わりになる関数もしくは、代替の方法をご存知でしたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

spresenseについては全くわかりませんが、Arduino Core Libraryの[実装](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/d9e5aa018c1624c7e3825ea84d69d01ff8094109/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/cores/spresense/time.c#L46)を見ると、`clock_gettime`なる関数を使っているようです。これは[SDKが提供するAPIのように見える](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/blob/33597a88e7fe6ce151ad892379d316d1fa1786e1/sched/clock/clock_gettime.c#L68)ので、これを呼ぶことができれば`millis`と同じ動作を実現できると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

SPRESENSE の Arduino コアライブラリの time.c に次の様に実装されているようです。

```
#include <time.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

... snip ...

uint64_t millis(void)
{
    struct timespec tp;

    /* Wait until RTC is available */
    while (g_rtc_enabled == false);

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (((uint64_t)tp.tv_sec) * 1000 + tp.tv_nsec / 1000000);
}
```

ご参考まで。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
上記のファイルを含めてコンパイルを実行して解決出来ました。